# How to delete decimals and place zeros in front of number dynamically in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe and I want to delete everything after the `.` and I want to delete the `.`
furthermore, I want to place zeroes in front of the numbers so every number has a length of 4.

As is:

```
|270.0            |  
|749.5            |  
|460.0            |  
|90.0             |  
|670.0            |    
|656.6666666666666|  
|1210.0           |
```

TO BE:

```
|0270|  
|0749|  
|0460|  
|0090|  
|0670|  
|0656|  
|1210|
```

Kind regards,

Wokter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`format_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#format_number) + [`lpad`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#lpad) functions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "number",
    F.expr("lpad(format_number(number, '####'), 4, '0')")
)

df1.show()
#+------+
#|number|
#+------+
#|  0270|
#|  0750|
#|  0460|
#|  0090|
#|  0670|
#|  0657|
#|  1210|
#+------+
```

Or `lpad` + `regexp_replace` :

```
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "number",
    F.lpad(F.regexp_replace("number", "\\.(.*)", ""), 4, '0')
)
```